# How to extend case class with type parameter?

Tags: scala

I have the following `case class` that I would like to extend:

```
case class Message[A](ackTo: ActorRef[Ack], msg: A)
```

I've tried:

```
case class KafkaMessage() extends Message[KafkaHealthEvent]
    with ServerHealthStreamer

case class SapMessage() extends Message[SapHealthEvent]
    with ServerHealthStreamer
```

But I do not know, how to extend it correctly. The whole type definition:

```
object ServerStreamer {

  sealed trait Ack

  object Ack extends Ack

  sealed trait ServerHealthStreamer

  case class Message[A](ackTo: ActorRef[Ack], msg: A)

  case class Init(ackTo: ActorRef[Ack]) extends ServerHealthStreamer

  case class KafkaMessage() extends Message[KafkaHealthEvent]
    with ServerHealthStreamer

  case class SapMessage() extends Message[SapHealthEvent]
    with ServerHealthStreamer

  case object Complete extends ServerHealthStreamer

  case class Fail(ex: Throwable) extends ServerHealthStreamer

}
```

How to extend it correctly?

Comment: You don't mention it, but I assume you're getting an error because you can't extend a case class and make another case class with it? Anyway, since you seem to be streaming, why not use akka streams directly?

Comment: case class is not used for inheritance or implementing traits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you can't `extend` a `case class`. So just make `Message` a normal `class` or `trait`

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a case class but the extended object cannot be a case class itself, only a class. Additionally, note that the case class which is being extended must have its properties initialised in the extending class' construction:

```
// Let KafkaActorRef extend ActorRef[Ack]
class KafkaMessage(kafkaActorRef: KafkaActorRef) extends Message[KafkaHealthEvent](kafkaActorRef, "someMessage")
```

Here you can see that the values of the extended case class are assigned in the class construction.